# Bold, Italic and Underline -vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts, label

My program makes labels bold, italic, or underline depending on the button clicked. But when I attempt to have both effects at once the first fades off.

```
Private Sub bold_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bold.Click

    Dim con4 As Control
    For Each con4 In Me.Controls
        Select Case con4.Name
            Case "Label1"
                If con4.Font.Bold = False Then
                    con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                Else
                    con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
                End If
            Case "Label2"
                If con4.Font.Bold = False Then
                    con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                Else
                    con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
                End If
```

...

```
         End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

This code goes up to Label24.

So I use the same procedure for 3 different buttons and they get me my result. But attempting to have 2 effects together overrides the previous one.

---

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

You override the font style with the very next test because you inspect-and-set all conditions only one at a time.

Combine the tests for each label once, then pick the right font:

```
If con4.Font.Bold = False Then
    If con4.Font.Italic = False Then
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold Or FontSryle.Italic)
    Else ' not italic
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    End If
Else ' not bold
    If con4.Font.Italic = False Then
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
    Else ' not italic
        con4.Font = New Font(con4.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
    End If
 End If
```

As you can see, this gets unwieldy very fast; especially if you are repeating the same code for 24 labels. So, step #1 would be to make this sequence a function.

Step #2 is to get rid of all those comparisons - adding Underline would add yet another level of `if..else..end if` for all of the separate cases! You can combine `FontStyle` bits with an `Or` to form the final value, and only then set it:

```
fontstyle = FontStyle.Regular
If cond4.Font.Bold = False Then
    fontstyle = fontStyle.Bold
End If
If cond4.Font.Italic = False Then
    fontstyle = fontstyle Or fontStyle.Italic
End If
If cond4.Font.Underline = False Then
    fontstyle = fontstyle Or fontStyle.Underline
End If
target.Font = New Font(con4.Font, fontstyle)
```

(This may not entirely be the correct syntax, but the general idea should be clear.)

Comment: Pause. I will edit my code to make things clearer. I can't understand your code.

Comment: well I get the Step1 part, which needs to be completed by me. In Step2, I don't know what is `fontstyle` since my program tells me `It is Enum type and can't be converted to expression`. Could you edit your answer and tell me where do I write your given code. It seems each `If`statement should be under a different button click event. Clarify please and thank you.

Comment: @TGamer: the first is specific behavior of your programming language. Look for a manual; I imagine you have to do something like `Dim fontstyle as FontStyle` (with "I imagine" I mean that I do not actually know and you should try and find it out yourself). The second: "get rid of all those comparisons", so this shorter, more efficient, and easier maintainable code would come *in place of* that long, long list of `if..else`.